# Plugging in d3-force-3d calculations into a 3-D graph renderer

Tags: javascript, d3.js, three.js, d3-force-directed

I am a threejs noob and my use case requires me to render force directed graphs in 3D. I am using d3-force-3d to calculate all the forces that are on the nodes of the graph. However, I've failed to find any library that takes those calculations into account and creates a 3 dimensional graph for the same.

I could find only one library that makes force directed graphs in 3D, which is [3d-force-graph](https://github.com/vasturiano/3d-force-graph), but it does not allow you to edit forces, which I need to.

Is there a library that directly plugs in d3 calculations and renders a 3D-graph?

Comment: https://bl.ocks.org/vasturiano/02affe306ce445e423f992faeea13521

Comment: I was talking about the same library in my answer. It doesn't let you edit forces.. :-)

Answer (score 1):

As of `v1.15.0`, [3d-force-graph](https://github.com/vasturiano/3d-force-graph) allows for manipulation of the d3 forces and decay parameters, using the methods `d3Force()`, `d3AlphaDecay()` and `d3VelocityDecay()`.

Here's an example with custom force configuration that adds collision detection to free moving nodes:
https://vasturiano.github.io/3d-force-graph/example/collision-detection/

Code from example:
https://github.com/vasturiano/3d-force-graph/tree/master/example/collision-detection